# Shift screen layout for the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the screen to move up when the keyboard is displayed:
I have added this inside the activity that displays the fragment.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

However, there is no change..

[image: Form][image: Form fields hidden when keyboard is displayed]

Comment: Do you have a ScrollView in your layout?

Comment: Hi I was missing the scrollview. it works now

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html). May be it can help you.

If its a fragment which is creating a problem, try adding this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to its activity.

Comment: Hi thanks for the link..i was missing a surrounding scrollview. I had already added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", so it was the missing scrollview